# Visual C++ output exits so fast

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio terminates my console application too fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726685/visual-studio-terminates-my-console-application-too-fast)

I am 100% new to Visual Studio C++. I am new to C++ too and I used netbeans up to now, with cygwin. Today I installed visual C++ 2012 and ran the following simple code

```
// HelloWorld.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

The console window came, and it went so fast without giving me a chance to see the output too, mentioning the following.

```
'HelloWorld.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\yohan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HelloWorld\Debug\HelloWorld.exe', Symbols loaded.
'HelloWorld.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloWorld.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloWorld.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'HelloWorld.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'HelloWorld.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
The program '[3436] HelloWorld.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I browsed the internet and some have suggested to set Project Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Debugging tab > Generate Debug info to "yes". This is set to yes already, but still no good. I am planning to work with opencv with this IDE too. So Please help!!!

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: You obviously shouldn't put in a `cin` into a real program unless you actually want to read in input.

What's happening is that your program is printing "Hello World", as you told it to, and then finishing.

VS, being a MS program, only creates a terminal for your program until it finishes, whereupon it closes the terminal.

In order to see the output, you can put this after your cout:

```
string buffer;
cin >> buffer;
```

This will wait for you to press enter before terminating the program.

Comment: You shouldn't normally do that as it makes your program behave differently from what is the norm for console applications, and it's unnecessary here. That said, yes, it will work.

Comment: @hvd: True; but since he's only learning, and the next logical step is a cin and user input anyway, in this case, it'll work.

Answer (score 4):

If you run the program separately from the IDE (through Ctrl+F5 instead of F5), it will not close the console window at the end but will print "Press any key to continue..." (without you modifying the source code in any way).

The down side of this approach is that all assertions and failures will lead to program crash, rather than being caught by the Visual Studio.

Comment: that's not entirely true: upon assertions for instance, a dialog will be shown asking to attach the debugger so you still have the chance to see what's happening in VS

Answer (score 2):

That is the normal behaviour for console applications that are called without an open console. For example, go to your system32 folder and double-click `attrib.exe`.

The easiest way to see the output is to set a breakpoint at the last line in your program.

Answer (score 0):

It's classed as a "hack" but for such a simple app like your's you could just use the line:

```
system(“pause”);
```

It's platform specific and slow but seems you are on Windows.

A Breakpoint is also a good way to pause execution. Once Main has executed your application is done, and that is what you are witnessing. Put a breakpoint on the last curly brace of Main.

```
char a = getchar();
```

Will pause and wait for you to enter a character.

Comment: That's `system("pause")` (with a lower-case s) I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you make console application it was to be logical - try to run your program from console.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a breakpoint at the end of your main, or call `getchar()`, or  `system("pause")` or execute your program through console

when setting breakpoint, make sure you are in debug mode