# Visual Studio Community 2015 Console Application Error on Start

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Here are the errors:

```
'ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Chris James\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x3344 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x369c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4498 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded 'c:\users\chris james\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x2b58 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3994 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[11144] ConsoleApplication3.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I can see the console using ctrl + f5 which I found out through another stack overflow question, but it runs and disappears when just using Start.
[Visual Studio terminates my console application too fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726685/visual-studio-terminates-my-console-application-too-fast)

This is my first program written in C# for event driven programming. I was wondering if I should be worried about future programs or can I bypass it everytime? I also enabled Symbols through `Debug>Options>Debugging>Symbols`, which changed my error from file not found to symbol loaded. Is there a better fix? I uninstalled, reinstalled, repaired, got rid of redistributables, and added older redistributables but couldn't find another solution. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace DelegateTutorial1
{
    public class MediaStorage
    {
        public delegate int PlayMedia();

        public void ReportResult(PlayMedia playerDelegate)
        {
            if (playerDelegate() == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Media played successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Media did not play successfully");
            }
        }
    }

    public class AudioPlayer
    {
        private int audioPlayerStatus;

        public int PlayAudioFile()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Simulating playing an audio file");
            audioPlayerStatus = 0;
            return audioPlayerStatus;
        }
    }

    public class VideoPlayer
    {
        private int videoPlayerStatus;

        public int PlayVideoFile()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Simulating a failed video file");
            videoPlayerStatus = -1;
            return videoPlayerStatus;
        }
    }

    public class Tester
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            MediaStorage myMediaStorage = new MediaStorage();
            AudioPlayer myAudioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
            VideoPlayer myVideoPlayer = new VideoPlayer();

            MediaStorage.PlayMedia audioPlayerDelegate = new MediaStorage.PlayMedia(myAudioPlayer.PlayAudioFile);
            MediaStorage.PlayMedia videoPlayerDelegate = new MediaStorage.PlayMedia(myVideoPlayer.PlayVideoFile);

            myMediaStorage.ReportResult(audioPlayerDelegate);
            myMediaStorage.ReportResult(videoPlayerDelegate);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Tester t = new Tester();
            t.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably add `Console.ReadKey()` after `t.Run()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's **not an error** at all, that's the **normal** beaviour.

If you start a *console application*, a new *console window* is shown and it will stay open as long as your process is running. Once your process has exited, the *console window* will be closed.

If you insert `Console.ReadKey()` at the end of your application, the window will stay open until you press any key.

So change this...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Tester t = new Tester();
    t.Run();
}
```

...to this...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Tester t = new Tester();
    t.Run();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

...and the *console window* will stay open until you press any key.

**In addition**: The *symbols* you "enabled" will help you if you want to debug into the .NET framework. It has nothing to do with the fact that the termination of the *console application* will close the *console window*.